# Creating a macro button to copy particular range in a column to another sheet with increasing column number so I can add new data

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

I am trying to create a macro which accomplishes the following:

If I am in Sheet1 and i put in values in column A, Rows 1-10, I'd click a button and it transfers the data to Sheet2 Column A. If put in data again and press button and this time it transfers to column B, and again then to C etc. I have created a copy Macro but I have no idea how to make it keep changing the output column. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub details()    

Dim currentWB  As String    

Dim futureWB As String    

    currentWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name    

    On Error Resume Next    
    Sheets("temporarysheet").Delete    
    On Error GoTo 0    

    Sheets.Add    
    ActiveSheet.Name = "temporarysheet"    

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select    

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then    
        Cells.Select    

        On Error Resume Next    

        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData    

        On Error GoTo 0    

    End If    

    Columns("B:B").Select    
    Selection.Copy    

    Sheets("temporarysheet").Select    
    Range("A1").Select    
    ActiveSheet.Paste    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False    

    If (Cells(1, 1) = "") Then    
        lastrow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row    

        If lastrow <> Rows.Count Then    
            Range("A1:A" & lastrow - 1).Select    
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp    
        End If    

    End If    

    Columns("A:A").Select    
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _    
                CopyToRange:=Range("B1"), Unique:=True    

    Columns("A:A").Delete    

    Cells.Select    
    Selection.Sort _    
            Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _    
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _    
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _    
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal    

    lMaxSupp = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    

    For suppno = 2 To lMaxSupp    

        Windows(currentWB).Activate    

        supName = Sheets("temporarysheet").Range("A" & suppno)    

        If supName <> "" Then    

            Workbooks.Add    
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs supName    
            futureWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name    

            Windows(currentWB).Activate    

            Sheets("Sheet1").Select    
            Cells.Select    

            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then    
                Selection.AutoFilter    
            End If    

            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & supName, _    
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"    

            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row    

            Rows("1:" & lastrow).Copy    

            Windows(futureWB).Activate    
            ActiveSheet.Paste    

            ActiveWorkbook.Save    
            ActiveWorkbook.Close    

        End If    

    Next    

    Sheets("temporarysheet").Delete    

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select    
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then    
        Cells.Select    
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData    
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you make the order in that you want what to happen more clear? That would really help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the order for what to happen? Do you mean the order of columns to which it will paste? That would just be alphabetical. i.e. to column A, column B, column C.... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after OP's specification to copy values only

your code has almost nothing to do with your question

as to this latter you could attach the following macro to your button:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copycolumn()
    Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| set your source sheet
    Dim destSht As Worksheet: Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") '<--| set your destination sheet

    GetFirstEmptyCell(destSht, 1).Resize(10).Value = sourceSht.Range("A1:A10").Value '<--| copy range "A1:A10" from 'source' sheet to 'destination' sheet first empty column in row 1
End Sub

Function GetFirstEmptyCell(sht As Worksheet, row As Long) As Range
    Set GetFirstEmptyCell = sht.Cells(row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) '<--| define the first non empty cell in passed row of passed worksheet
    If Not IsEmpty(GetFirstEmptyCell) Then Set GetFirstEmptyCell = GetFirstEmptyCell.Offset(, 1) '<--| if it's not empty then shift one column to the right
End Function
```

just change the relevant data (sheet names, ranges, row) to match your actual ones

Comment: Hey, thanks for this script. However, it copies the formula for the cells. I'd like it to copy just the data in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code you have seems to be copying over the B column, rather then the A column, from the input sheet - I've taken your code and just tweeked it:

```
Sub details()

Dim currentWB  As String

Dim futureWB As String

    currentWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("temporarysheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "temporarysheet"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        Cells.Select

        On Error Resume Next

        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

        On Error GoTo 0

    End If

    Columns("A:A").Select ' Changed from Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("temporarysheet").Select
    Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select 'Changed to move to the column immediately to the right of the pasted data
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If (Cells(1, 1) = "") Then
        lastrow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        If lastrow <> Rows.Count Then
            Range("A1:A" & lastrow - 1).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If

    End If

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=Range("B1"), Unique:=True

    Columns("A:A").Delete

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Sort _
            Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    lMaxSupp = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For suppno = 2 To lMaxSupp

        Windows(currentWB).Activate

        supName = Sheets("temporarysheet").Range("A" & suppno)

        If supName <> "" Then

            Workbooks.Add
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs supName
            futureWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

            Windows(currentWB).Activate

            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Cells.Select

            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
                Selection.AutoFilter
            End If

            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & supName, _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"

            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            Rows("1:" & lastrow).Copy

            Windows(futureWB).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close

        End If

    Next

    Sheets("temporarysheet").Delete

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        Cells.Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

End Sub
```

I haven't looked through the rest of your code but I'm assuming it's fine ( although it could definitely be cleaned up!)